# What is the origin of the meaning of 'counter' to express the surface on which goods or money is counted?

Tags: etymology, british-english, north-american-english

The OED does not appear to list the meaning of the noun 'counter' which conveys the concept of a flat surface over which goods or money is counted, except that it lists the verb 'to counter' as having one meaning in relation to furnishing an establishment 'with a counter'.

My Oxford Dictionary of English states the meaning and attributes it to 'N American' but without any estimate of date or reference.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counter) has :

> 3: a level surface (such as a table, shelf or display case) over which transactions are conducted or food is served or on which goods are displayed or work is conducted

I am interested in the etymology of the word as the same concept is expressed in Koine Greek, a [*trapeza*](https://biblehub.com/greek/5132.htm) being a table and a [*trapezite*](https://biblehub.com/greek/5132.htm) being a banker.

What is the history of the word 'counter' as meaning a flat surface on which items are counted ?

Comment: Are you sure you've actually checked in the OED? Oxford produce other dictionaries, for instance Lexico (formerly ODO), far less comprehensive. // Etymon has the etymology of this sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did check the OED online but missed the necessary. However DjinTonic has supplied it for me, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the OED:

> **counter** (n.3)
>
> **Etymology**: < Anglo-Norman *counteour, countour*, in Old French *conteoir.
> -eor, -oer*, whence *conteour, contouer*, in 14–15th cent.
> *comptouer, comptouoir*, modern French *comptoir* < Latin *computātōrium*
> (in medieval Latin 1364, Du Cange), < *computāre* to compute, count +
> -orium suffix. As this became, like the counter n.2, *countour*, -or in Anglo-Norman, they are both counter in modern English. The form
> *cowntewery* points to an Anglo-Norman *counteori* or *countoueri*
>
> II. A place where accounts are kept, or exchanges made.
>
> †3. A table or desk for counting money, keeping accounts, etc.; a
> bureau. *Obsolete*. [Citations c1369–1587]
>
> 4. a. A banker's or money-changer's table; also, the table in a shop on which the money paid by purchasers is counted out, and across which
>    goods are delivered. The tradesman stands **behind the counter**; goods
>    are sold and money paid **over the counter**. In modern times the
>    shop-counter is also used for the display of goods, but this is not
>    implied in the name.
>
> α.
> 1688  *He [is]..behind a Counter or
> Counting Table.*
>
> β.
> 1699 *Then from the Compter he takes down the File.*

Comment: Thank you. I should have gone to SpecSavers.